# python OpenCV - add alpha channel to RGB image

Tags: python, opencv

What is the best way to convert RGB image to RGBA in python using opencv?

Let's say I have one array with shape

```
(185, 198, 3) - it is RGB
```

and the other is alpha mask with shape `(185, 198)`

How to merge them and save to file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### This is the fastest Python solution.

```py
# Tell OpenCV to copy the 3 channels and add an empty alpha channel.
rgba = cv2.cvtColor(rgb_data, cv2.COLOR_RGB2RGBA)

# Then copy the dedicated alpha mask image to the last channel of the
# final image.
cv2.mixChannels((alpha_data,), (rgba,), (0,3,))

# Alternative method, if you want to copy the mask of another image,
# from its alpha channel (index 3).
cv2.mixChannels((other_image,), (rgba,), (3,3,))
```

In both cases, you need to ensure that the alpha channel dimensions are the same as the target image's dimensions, of course.

This is the **fastest** OpenCV technique available in Python!

You might wonder why we don't use the basic Numpy techniques of `rgba[:, :, 3] = alpha_data` (single channel source) or `rgba[:, :, 3] = other_image[:, :, 3]` (multi channel source). We avoid that because Numpy is **very slow.**

Here are some Python benchmarks compared to the accepted and highest voted answers, using a **4K resolution** test image:

- Accepted Answer: **6.27ms**

```py
python -m timeit -s "import numpy as np; import cv2; x = np.zeros([2160,3840,4], np.uint8); x[:,:,3] = 255; x[:,:,2] = 255; x[:,:,1] = 100; y = cv2.cvtColor(x, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2RGB)" "b_channel, g_channel, r_channel = cv2.split(y); img_BGRA = cv2.merge((b_channel, g_channel, r_channel, x[:,:,3]))"
```

- Highest voted answer (cvtColor technique), copying alpha channel from another image via Numpy "view" manipulation: **2.78ms**

```py
python -m timeit -s "import numpy as np; import cv2; x = np.zeros([2160,3840,4], np.uint8); x[:,:,3] = 255; x[:,:,2] = 255; x[:,:,1] = 100; y = cv2.cvtColor(x, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2RGB)" "rgba = cv2.cvtColor(y, cv2.COLOR_RGB2RGBA); rgba[:, :, 3] = x[:,:,3]"
```

- Highest voted answer (cvtColor technique), copying alpha channel from a dedicated single-channel alpha image via Numpy: **2.58ms**

```py
python -m timeit -s "import numpy as np; import cv2; x = np.zeros([2160,3840,4], np.uint8); x[:,:,3] = 42; x[:,:,2] = 255; x[:,:,1] = 100; y = cv2.cvtColor(x, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2RGB); alpha_data = x[:,:,3].copy()" "rgba = cv2.cvtColor(y, cv2.COLOR_RGB2RGBA); rgba[:, :, 3] = alpha_data"
```

- My technique with `cvtColor` and `mixChannels`, copying alpha channel from another multi-channel image: **2.47ms**

```py
python -m timeit -s "import numpy as np; import cv2; x = np.zeros([2160,3840,4], np.uint8); x[:,:,3] = 42; x[:,:,2] = 255; x[:,:,1] = 100; y = cv2.cvtColor(x, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2RGB)" "rgba = cv2.cvtColor(y, cv2.COLOR_RGB2RGBA); cv2.mixChannels((x,), (rgba,), (3,3,))"
```

- My technique with `cvtColor` and `mixChannels`, copying alpha channel from a dedicated single-channel alpha image: **2.2ms**

```py
python -m timeit -s "import numpy as np; import cv2; x = np.zeros([2160,3840,4], np.uint8); x[:,:,3] = 42; x[:,:,2] = 255; x[:,:,1] = 100; y = cv2.cvtColor(x, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2RGB); alpha_data = x[:,:,3].copy()" "rgba = cv2.cvtColor(y, cv2.COLOR_RGB2RGBA); cv2.mixChannels((alpha_data,), (rgba,), (0,3,))"
```

The reason why `cvtColor` is so fast is because OpenCV's `cvtColor` is accelerated by OpenCL and rapidly copies the 3 channels and creates a blank alpha channel. In fact, the `cvtColor` step takes only 0.17 milliseconds to copy the 3 color channels and create a blank alpha channel.

Compare that to all the extra work of the "accepted answer"; having to split the image into 3 separate channel images, and then merging them all back again. That's a lot of wasteful work.

In fact, OpenCV's `cvtColor` even beats most Numpy APIs, since Numpy isn't OpenCL-accelerated and is actually very slow at copying/manipulating image channel data (Numpy internally copies things 1 byte at a time, via old-school nested loops).

As a perfect example of Numpy's slowness, a massive 2.61 milliseconds is spent by the single `rgba[:, :, 3] = x[:,:,3]` Numpy operation which just copies one single channel. Despite the fact that Numpy uses "data views" to isolate the channel without copying any extra memory (when creating the right-hand view operation), it's still incredibly slow.

So the more we can do within pure OpenCV while avoiding Numpy, the better.

What OpenCV operations are available then?

Well, there's `rgba[:, :, 3] = cv2.extractChannel(x, 3)`, but that ends up being slower than Numpy, since it creates a brand new image on the right hand operation, and it then still involves Numpy's slow "copy byte by byte" mechanism for the actual copying. So... that's not good enough! What we would really need is a dedicated OpenCV function to copy a specific channel from image A to image B.

Luckily, OpenCV has *exactly* such a function, which takes two lists of source and destination images, and a list of channel pairs (source and destination channel index), which is how I sped up things even further: `cv2.mixChannels((other_image,), (rgba,), (3,3,))`. That technique works for both multi-channel and single-channel alpha sources, as seen at the top of my answer, in the code examples.

The [mixChannels](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga51d768c270a1cdd3497255017c4504be) operation is much faster than Numpy, but I've only tested it for copying one channel, the alpha channel (3rd zero-based channel index aka 4th channel). I suspect that it would always win over Numpy even when copying multiple channels, but someone would have to benchmark that compared to multi-channel "view copying" in Numpy, if you need to copy multiple channels. But that's not what this question was about!

Anyway, there you all have it. The **fastest** technique for adding an alpha channel and copying alpha channel data into it via pure Python!

**PS:** If you have a RGBA image and you only want the RGB channels (you want to delete the alpha channel), then the `cvtColor` technique is yet again the fastest:

```py
rgb = cv2.cvtColor(rgba, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2RGB)
```

Always remember these rules: OpenCV is faster than Numpy, and Numpy is faster than Python. So always do your operations with pure OpenCV functions when possible!

For a deeper article which I wrote years ago about all of this (a big warning against using "clever Numpy tricks", and how slow they actually are), check out this link:

https://answers.opencv.org/question/219040/fastest-way-to-convert-bgr-rgb-aka-do-not-use-numpy-magic-tricks/

Answer (score 76):

With opencv3, this should work:

Python

```
# First create the image with alpha channel
rgba = cv2.cvtColor(rgb_data, cv2.COLOR_RGB2RGBA)

# Then assign the mask to the last channel of the image
rgba[:, :, 3] = alpha_data
```

C++

```
# First create the image with alpha channel
cv::cvtColor(rgb_data, rgba , cv::COLOR_RGB2RGBA);

# Split the image for access to alpha channel
std::vector<cv::Mat>channels(4);
cv::split(rgba, channels);

# Assign the mask to the last channel of the image
channels[3] = alpha_data;

# Finally concat channels for rgba image
cv::merge(channels, 4, rgba);
```

Comment: This works like charm. This answer must be the accepted Answer

Comment: @kaanoner python: Can someone explain how this works? I am getting unexpected results - 3 does nothing, 0-2 produce various colours, and I don't understand how it's supposed to work.

Comment: cvtcolor creates an extra channel for alpha layer on top of your three channel rgb data. you then assign to this new channel (by selecting it with [:,:,3]) your alpha data which is one channel. in the end you have four channel rgba image filled with the combination of your rgb and alpha channels.

Comment: This is the easiest method

Comment: @kaanoner You are absolutely right that `cvtColor` is the correct way to convert an RGB image to a RGBA image. Your answer is 2.54x faster than the accepted answer. However, **I've created another technique which is even faster:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/77974549/8874388

Answer (score 44):

You may use [`cv2.merge()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#merge) to add the alpha channel to the given RGB image, but first you need to split the RGB image to `R, G and B` channels, as per the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#merge):

> Python: cv2.merge(mv[, dst])
>
> - mv – input array or vector of matrices to be merged; all the matrices in mv must have the same size and the same depth.

And this can be done as:

```
b_channel, g_channel, r_channel = cv2.split(img)

alpha_channel = np.ones(b_channel.shape, dtype=b_channel.dtype) * 50 #creating a dummy alpha channel image.

img_BGRA = cv2.merge((b_channel, g_channel, r_channel, alpha_channel))
```

Comment: One might want to do `alpha_channel = alpha_channel.astype(np.uint8)`, ie make sure all channel have the same dtype.

Comment: `rgba = cv2.cvtColor(rgb_data, cv2.COLOR_RGB2RGBA)` . This should solve

Comment: **Warning: I benchmarked this accepted answer, and it's 2.54x slower than my answer:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/77974549/8874388

Answer (score 8):

Since OpenCV images are just Numpy arrays, you can do this in one-line, nice and fast with Numpy. So here is the setup code:

```
import numpy as np

# We'll synthesise a random image and a separate alpha channel full of 128 - semitransparent
im    = np.random.randint(0,256,(480,640,3), dtype=np.uint8)
alpha = np.full((480,640), 128, dtype=np.uint8)
```

And here is the solution which is simply to stack the alpha channel onto the image in the *"depth"* axis, hence `dstack()`:

```
result = np.dstack((im, alpha))
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is an another simple example using Grabcut, it helps to get the right order of channels when saving the image on disk vs `pyplot`.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('image.jpg')

mask = np.zeros(img.shape[:2], np.uint8)
bgdModel = np.zeros((1,65), np.float64)
fgdModel = np.zeros((1,65), np.float64)
rect = (50, 50, 450, 290)

# Grabcut 
cv2.grabCut(img, mask, rect, bgdModel, fgdModel, 5, cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)

r_channel, g_channel, b_channel = cv2.split(img) 
a_channel = np.where((mask==2)|(mask==0), 0, 255).astype('uint8')  

img_RGBA = cv2.merge((r_channel, g_channel, b_channel, a_channel))
cv2.imwrite("test.png", img_RGBA)

# Now for plot correct colors : 
img_BGRA = cv2.merge((b_channel, g_channel, r_channel, a_channel))

plt.imshow(img_BGRA), plt.colorbar(),plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import skimage.exposure



path_input_image="./input_image.png"


input_image = cv2.imread(path_input_image2, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)


input_image_alphachann = np.full((input_image.shape[0],input_image.shape[1]), 128, dtype=np.uint8)

output_image = np.dstack((input_image, input_image_alphachann))


print(input_image.shape)
print(output_image.shape)
#(400, 200, 3); 3 channell rgb
#(400, 200, 4); 4c channel rgba



print(input_image.dtype)
print(output_image.dtype)
# uint8




path_output_image=path_input_image+'.alpha.png'
cv2.imwrite(path_output_image, output_image)
```

Answer (score 4):

I'll post here my answer in C++ since it may be helpful to others (there are already enough answers in python):

```cpp
  std::vector<cv::Mat> matChannels;
  cv::split(mat, matChannels);
  
  // create alpha channel
  cv::Mat alpha(...);
  matChannels.push_back(alpha);

  cv::merge(matChannels, dst);
```