# How to apply the mask which is not a cv2.THRESH_BINARY mask to cover origin image with python-opencv?

Tags: opencv, mask

The mask edge is soft, like this:

[image]

and Result with this mask in photoshop is:

[image]

After cv2.bitwise_and ,So bad the result is!

[image]

How can I handel this like photoshop,or any other method in python-opencv can do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If  you want the transparent effect like in photoshop, you need to use an alpha channel. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32290096/python-opencv-add-alpha-channel-to-rgb-image).

If you want to composite the image with another background, you can use the alpha matting formula `I = aF+(1-a)B`, where `a` the alpha, `F` the foreground and `B` the background. Like this:

```
ex_alpha = np.repeat(alpha[:, :, np.newaxis], 3, axis=2)
output = (foreground*ex_alpha) + (1-ex_alpha)*background
```

The repeat exists because foreground/background are 3-channels while alpha is 1-channel.

Comment: Yes ,The key is alpha ！ I generate a png image,The RGB channel is origin image, and The mask data as alpha .It works.  Thank you .

Comment: @叶业力 Feel free to accept the answer if it solves your problem!