# Adding transparency to the program written in Python

Tags: python, arrays, image, graphics, photoshop

I found the code below from one of the posts here very useful, but would someone, please, tell me how to add an alpha channel to that?

I just need to add opacity from 0 to 100%. I know ppm file supports it and I am completely new to Python.

I tried adding the 4-th parameter as RGB(A), but it didn't work.

I need exactly a *.ppm file generated by the program below with transparency added to it.

```
import array
width,height = 800,600

PPMheader = 'P6\n' +str(width) + ' ' +str(height) + '\n255\n'

# Create and fill a red PPM image
image = array.array('B', [255, 0, 0] * width * height)

# Save as PPM image
with open('result.ppm', 'wb') as f:
   f.write(bytearray(PPMheader, 'ascii'))
   image.tofile(f)
```

Comment: Please see if this helps [python OpenCV - add alpha channel to RGB image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32290096/python-opencv-add-alpha-channel-to-rgb-image#:~:text=cvtcolor%20creates%20an%20extra%20channel,your%20rgb%20and%20alpha%20channels).

Comment: "*I know ppm file supports it*" How do you come to that conclusion? https://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html doesn't say anything about an alpha canal ...  Citing from that document: "*Each pixel is a triplet of red, green, and blue samples, in that order.*"

Comment: There may be an extend specification I'm not aware of (didn't search very much though). If that's the case could you please provide an according document, so we can see what has to be added ...

Comment: @journpy Probably not, because it seems that particular image format (PPM) does not support an alpha channel. Ie even if you add a fourth value to each pixel, any viewer following the specifications won't be able to correctly interpret the image.

Comment: How did you get on with my answer?

Answer (score 1):

The PPM image format is part of the [NetPBM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm#) suite and only supports 3 RGB channels of 8/16 bits/sample data - but without any alpha/transparency channel.

There is a widely-used extension to that called [PAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm#PAM_graphics_format) *"Portable Arbitrary Map"* which allows an alpha/transparency channel. The format is understood by many of the NetPBM tools and also by **ImageMagick**, e.g. you can convert a PAM image to PNG with **ImageMagick** using `magick INPUT.PAM OUTPUT.PNG`

So, I am hoping that will work for you. Here is an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np

# Define image dimension and centre in x/y directions
width,height = 800,600
cx = width//2
cy = height//2

PAMheader = f'P7\nWIDTH {width}\nHEIGHT {height}\nDEPTH 4\nMAXVAL 255\nTUPLTYPE RGB_ALPHA\nENDHDR\n'

# Create and fill a fully opaque red PAM image, 4 means RGBA channels
image = np.full((height, width, 4), [255,0,0,255], np.uint8)

# Make big transparent hole in centre
image[cy-160:cy+160, cx-160:cx+160, 3] = 0

# Make slightly smaller semi-transparent hole, i.e. A channel is 128, i.e. image [:,:,3] = 128
image[cy-80:cy+80, cx-80:cx+80, 3] = 128

# Save as PAM image
with open('result.pam', 'wb') as f:
   f.write(PAMheader.encode())
   image.tofile(f)
```

[image]